# TFSBuild: Disabling Code-Analysis for one project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild, code-analysis

We have a large VS2012 solution (~250 projects) that is 90% C#. 2 of the 3 C++ projects use the 'v110' Platform Toolset. The third has to use the 'v110_xp' toolset for compatibility with a third party library.  Our nightly TFS (2012) build is configured with 'Perform Code Analysis' set to **Always**.

Unfortunately, the v110_xp platform does not support code analysis ([MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx)).  This results with the following build failure:

> **Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.v110_xp.targets(28,5): error MSB8026: Static analysis is not supported with the current platform toolset.**

Any ideas how we can prevent code analysis from running on this single project without enabling (by default) code analysis for all projects (except the one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the build to be "As Configured" and select I your solution which projects to run analytics on and which not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547175.aspx

Comment: I saw that option, but I was hoping for some means to prevent CA for one project even when in the 'Always' mode.  As switching to 'As Configured' requires us to touch every project's settings and/or create a whole new configuration per project.

Comment: So you want to set "always" but not! You have to set the configuration once by configuring each project and then checking in. Job done, easy and simple..

Comment: If you have 10 projects maybe, but we have ~250.  Our CI build takes ~15 min, our build with CA takes ~65 min.  And when developers want to build release they shouldn't need to run CA.  The only solution I see is to add a 3rd configuration 'Release_CA'.  But, then, we'd have to maintain 2 configurations Release and Release_CA.  I don't care if Debug is broken, but keeping Release_CA and Release in sync could be nightmare.

Comment: Ok... So tye first thing I would do is break that frankin'solution down into manageable chunks. Push some code components into NuGet packages and fix the underlying problem 

Comment: It seems the "as configured" is our only hope in this scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the following helped me:

```
Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset
```

Change was from v120_xp  to v120